# Reason why a Temp Table seems to extend its scope in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, temp-tables

I faced a strange situation

i use a temp table created with the select into technique like

```
select *
into #MyTempTable
from TABLE
```

In principle the scope pf `#MyTempTable` is limited to the process id.

but even if i explicitly use

```
drop table #MyTempTable
```

when i run again

```
select *
into #MyTempTable
from TABLE
```

i have an error that temp table already exists.

Why this can occur? I never faced this issue before, i use this technique since years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you definitely running the code in the same window? If you're dropping the table in another window it won't drop it properly.

I always consider it best practice to run code that checks if it exists before explicitly creating the table (rather than `SELECT INTO`). Something like this;

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempTable
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (RowNumber int identity(1,1), OtherField nvarchar(max))
```

Comment: Yes, this is very good. In fact i tried your approach and my problem disappeaerd. the `select into` technique is a time saver only.

Comment: Yeah, it can be a bit of a pain though (it's made you come to stack overflow to ask about it). Getting in the habit of the code above can actually be more of a time saver in the long term.